# how to get the location and the color of a pixel in workspace by clicking with the mouse - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have some fiducial points in an image and I need the user to select the first point and get the coordinates of that point and the colour vector in workspace.

At the moment I have only found:

- `datacursor`, but it only gives the location, not the colour
- `impixel`, apparently should give both, but it is a bit confusing and it's not working very well
- `imroi` only gives location too from what I've read

Can you please help me with this? Also, can the colour vector be in the Lab colorspace  (transform the image first, and then click in the point)?
Many thanks!

Comment: The second question is more confusing. What do you want to achieve exactly? (Lab color space?)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment until now. The mail goal is to get automatically the a and b values (of the Lab color space) of the pixel that I click in workspace to be used later in the script (I'm working in color segmentation). At the moment I can get the rgb values using impixel thanks to your advice, but I converted my image into Lab color space I still get the rgb values with impixel,no a and b. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code. You can end `impixel` at the first mouse click (or sample several points) by pressing the return key. `c` and `r` will be the location, and `P` the RGB value.

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');  %read the image in I
imshow(I);                    %display I
[c,r,P] = impixel(I)          %get the pixel(s)

% "return" key to end impixel
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed! But now I wonder: is it possible to change my photo to Lab colorspace and then get the a and b values with the impixel instead of the rgb values?

Comment: And regarding the pixel coordinates, I want to order the fiducial points in a clockwise direction, and my idea is to do it by angles. However I want the zero angle, the starting point, in the direction of the first fiducial point (at an angle) and not in the horizontal direction. Is it possible to change the atan2 function to do this? Is there any other way to solve this problem? Many thanks again!